# How to export/share freemarker macro?

Tags: freemarker

I want to export a jar with maven `<packaging>jar</packaging>`. And after adding dependency to that jar in another project, I can `import` the macros.

How to do that?

EDIT:

With java, I can export `com.example.a` to a jar file, and use it in `com.example.b` with `import`. I want the similar for freemarker.

I've search with keyword `package, bundle, export, module` without any luck. I thought this should be a very common senario. I really do not know how to elaborate more.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @GautamSavaliya I did my best.

Answer (score 0):

If the `TemplateLoader` of your `Configuration` sees those resources, you can just `#import`/`#include` them, as you did before. Usually you need a `MultiTemplateLoader`, then add your "normal" `TemplateLoader` to it (which loads the application-specific FTL-s), and also a `ClassTemplateLoader` that points to the package which contains the reused FTL-s.

Comment: Where should I put the templates so that it can be seen by other projects? I only find java classes in my jar.

Comment: Jars can and often do contain arbitrary files (resources) together with `.class` files. So you can just store the `.ftl` files in the subdirectory that corresponds to the desired java package.

Comment: I did that and only .java in my jar. Can you show me a screenshot of how the directory structure should be?

Comment: You shouldn't have `.java` files in your jars, but `.class` files, and in this case, `.ftl` files. For example, inside your jar you could have `com/example/myproject/commons/templates/my-commons.ftl`, and then you have that jar as dependency, and so if you have `new ClassTemplateLoader(..., "com/example/myproject/commons/templates")` among the template loaders, then you can issue `<#import '/my-commons.ftl' as my>`. As of how to produce such a jar file, refer to the documentation of the build tool you use.